# PL/SQL because I am getting an error when executing the object body?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tipo_persona AS OBJECT --head
(
nombre VARCHAR2(25),
coche coche_obj,
MEMBER PROCEDURE mostrar_persona
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY tipo_persona --body
AS
MEMBER PROCEDURE mostrar_persona
 IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nombre || ' ' || coche);
  END;
END;
```

Error during the execute:

> Error(6,26): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to `||`

Comment: _wrong number or types of arguments when calling '||'_

Comment: What is coche_obj?

Comment: another object.

Comment: Compatible with `||`?

Comment: What are you expecting to see in the output - an object reference, or all the fields in the object? Oracle won't automatically serialise (if that's the right term) an object to a string format that [the concatenation operator `||`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Concatenation-Operator.html#GUID-08C10738-706B-4290-B7CD-C279EBC90F7E) recognises. You'll need to specify the field(s) you want.